# How do you choose storage engines for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, storage-engines

Ok the question is obviously wrong as it stands, but I'm wondering how can I choose storage implementations on Oracle as I would for MySQL, say I want one table to MyIsam like and another for Archiving only and one Black Hole style for test purposes. How would I go around to doing this within a single Schema, or something similar that would meet these needs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle does not have a storage engine concept like Mysql does. It stores all tables in its own format in datafiles. What you can do is use different tablespaces and store them on different disks whose performance characteristics may be different.

The concepts guide may help you understand how Oracle works.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm):

```
CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
```

and select an access driver to use with it.

As for now, `Oracle` has `ORACLE_LOADER` to access `CSV` and like text tables (read-only), and `ORACLE_DATAPUMP` to read and write binary data (in custom format).

Comment: Have a link to a tutorial on that?

Comment: Sorry, it seems you cannot develop one youself, yet :)

Comment: Thanks for the try anyways. That might come in handy for another thing I need to do.

Comment: External tables are not a storage engine concept. They are used to read text files from Oracle and their purpose is to load data from text files into the database. You cannot perform DML operations 
on those.